# Image cannot be saved using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum to photo album

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios5, ios4, uiimageview

I have a save button called save to photo album. On top of the button is the small UIImageView where user can click the button below to save the actual size of the photo to photo album. My problem is that when I click the save button, it shows an error : Unable to save image to Photo Album.

I think I have done it right but my experience is too limited.

H file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController  {

    IBOutlet UIButton *btnReturn;
    IBOutlet UIButton *savePhoto;
    IBOutlet UIImage *saveImage;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btnReturn;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *savePhoto;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImage *saveImage;

-(IBAction) saveToPhotoAlbum;

@end
```

Below is my code:

```
-(IBAction) saveToPhotoAlbum{

    NSString *saveMyPhoto=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.png"];

    UIImage *saved=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:saveMyPhoto]; 

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)UIImagePNGRepresentation(saved)];
    [imageData writeToFile:(NSString *)saved atomically:YES ];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(saved, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    }

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    UIAlertView *alert;


    if (error)
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                           message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album." 
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    else 
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" 
                                           message:@"Image saved to Photo Album." 
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: What's the actual error (i.e. add `NSLog(@"%@", error);` in your image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo: method.

Comment: The image is Unable to save image to Photo Album. The program can run successfully. It's just that it cannot save. Any possibility of my code not right?

Comment: No, that's not the error, that's just what you've typed in as the message to your alert. What happens when you add the line `NSLog(@"%@", error);` in your image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo: method - there should be an error output into the console. We need to know what that is.

Comment: OK. This is the error. Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3304 "Failed to encode image for saved photos." UserInfo=0x7857630 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7851f20 "Failed to encode image for saved photos.", NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to encode image for saved photos.}

Comment: What should I do? I just wanted to save the image successfully.

Comment: The error means that you've got the wrong encoding for your data. Are you sure that your UIImage is loading correctly?

Comment: My UIImageView is a small picture from jpg. And my IBAction is the real UIImage png format that I wanted to save to photo album. I've included my H file here. How to make sure my UIImage is loading?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", saved);` - it should say something like <UIImage ...>. It shouldn't say nothing or `null`.

Comment: I would like to thank you very much. The problem solved now. The way you questioning me to raise the root issue allow me to trouble shoot more & dig deep down the practical experience. Thanks again. More mistakes, the more I learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines look really really suspect :

```
NSString *saveMyPhoto=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.png"];
...
UIImage *saved = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:saveMyPhoto]; 
...
[imageData writeToFile:(NSString *)saved atomically:YES ];
```

What are you expecting this to do? You get a path to an image, load it and then save it again but you've cast a UIImage to an NSString and are hoping it will magically turn into a valid path on the disk?

As for the question you're asking, are you sure that your image is a valid image?

Comment: I just want it to save successfully to photo album. That's all. Yes my image is in png format. Any recommendation about my code?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a UIImage object and load the image from file. Then just call the UIIMageWriteToSavedPhotoAlbum function and pass the UIImage object as the first parameter and then the rest could all be NIL. See the [Apple SDK documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum)